# Graphite + Collectd - How to plot memory used percentage for each host?

Tags: graphite, collectd

I have graphite+collectd setup to collect system related metrics. This question concerns with the memory plugin for collectd.

My infra has this format for collecting memory usage data using collectd:

```
<cluster>.<host>.memory.memory-{buffered,cached,free,used}
```

I want to plot the percentage of memory used for each host.

So basically, I have to do something like this:

```
divideSeries(sumSeriesWithWildCards(*.*.memory.memory-{buffered,cached,free},1),sumSeriesWithWildCards(*.*.memory.memory-{buffered,cached,free,used}),1)
```

But I am not able to do this, as divideSeries wants the divisor metric to return only one metric.

I basically want a single target to monitor all hosts in a cluster.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

try this one:

```
asPercent(host.memory.memory-used, sumSeries(host.memory.memory-{used,free,cached,buffered}))
```

you'll get a graph of memory usage in percents for one hosts. Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work with wildcards (multiple hosts).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for multiple nodes with regex.

```
alias(asPercent(sumSeries(collectd.nodexx*_internal_cloudapp_net.memory.memory.used), sumSeries(collectd.nodexx*_internal_cloudapp_net.memory.memory.{used,free,cached,buffered})),"Memory Used")

alias(asPercent(sumSeries(collectd.nodexx*_internal_cloudapp_net.memory.memory.{cached,buffered}), sumSeries(collectd.nodexx*_internal_cloudapp_net.memory.memory.{used,free,cached,buffered})),"Memory Cached")

alias(asPercent(sumSeries(collectd.nodexx*_internal_cloudapp_net.memory.memory.free), sumSeries(collectd.nodexx*_internal_cloudapp_net.memory.memory.{used,free,cached,buffered})),"Memory Free")
```